# Laravel 8 - Queue jobs timeout, Fixed by clearing cache & restarting horizon

Tags: laravel, redis, laravel-queue, azure-redis-cache, laravel-jobs

My queue jobs all run fairly seamlessy in our production server, but about every 2 - 3 months I start getting a lot of timeout exceeded/too many attempts exceptions.

Our app is running with event sourcing and many events are queued so neededless to say we have a lot of jobs passing through the system (100 - 200k per day generally).

I have not found the root cause of the issues yet, but a simple re-deploy through Laravel Envoyer fixes the issue. This is most likely due to the `cache:clear` command being run.

Currently, the cache is handled by Redis and is on the same server as the app. I was considering moving the cache to its own server/instance but this still does not help me with the root cause.

Does anyone have any ideas what might be going on here and how I can diagnose/fix it? I am guessing the cache is just getting overloaded/running out of space/leaking etc. over time but not really sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

Check :

- The version of your redis make an update of the predis package
- The version of your Laravel
- Your server
  I hope I gave you some solutions